# set src img tag in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

What the proper way to set src  in img tag from js into asp.net? Because I try this way, it doesn't show up. The data from sql server and I'm using jquery and ajax to call the data. It's already show up in console but don't know why it be like that

**In console**

`<img class="img-fluid px-3 px-sm-4 mt-3 mb-4" id="img" style="width: 25rem;" alt="learning" src="~/images/Capture205450514.PNG">`

**.js**

```
let q = data[questionIndex];
    if (q.img != null) {
        $("#img").attr("src", q.img);
    }
    else {
        img.style.display = "none";
    }
```

**.cshtml**

`<img class="img-fluid px-3 px-sm-4 mt-3 mb-4" id="img" style="width: 25rem;" >`

Comment: Some more context of data passed to q var. Also img object in else statement is undefined too. More detail would be handy as js to asp.net doesn’t make sense there is no asp.net code in your question, just js

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's already appear in console like this ` <img class="img-fluid px-3 px-sm-4 mt-3 mb-4" id="img" style="width: 25rem;" alt="learning" src="~/images/Capture205450514.PNG">  ` but, it doesn't show up. I just ask if have any method when using asp.net

Answer (score 0):

Modify your src. You have not set it up correctly. If you are working with JavaScript, this is client-side and should be done this way.

```
<img class="img-fluid px-3 px-sm-4 mt-3 mb-4" id="img" style="width: 25rem;" alt="learning" src="images/download.jpg">
```

You did not mention what you are doing on localhost or not because you may need to
Absolute URL

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to fix the **Relative URL**. Using `~` in URL doesn't make a valid URL.

- If the `images` directory is at the root of your web application then use `"/images/Capture205450514.PNG"`
- If the `images` directory is at the same level as of your HTML page then use `"./images/Capture205450514.PNG"` or simply `"images/Capture205450514.PNG"`
- If the `images` directory is at one level higher than your HTML page then use `"../images/Capture205450514.PNG"`

[Click here for reference](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp)